# saving the file in current date and time format

Tags: python, timestamp, android-sensors

I'm logging sensor readings with timestamps.

I want to save the file in current date and time name format, like 2019-08-20-15-20.

Any idea how to make it?.

```
write_fmtt = " ".join("%4.8f" for _ in timestamped_camera_readings)
timestamped_camera_readings = np.append(float(timestamp),[arr1 , arr2 , arr3 , arr4])
write_fmtt += " %.0f"

with open("sensor reading.txt", "ab") as ff:
     np.savetxt(ff, np.expand_dims(timestamped_camera_readings, axis=0),fmt='%f')
```

Comment: please clarify: what do you mean by "current date and time name format"? what specificly is not working in your code?

Comment: you mean the file's name?

Comment: why not use datetime.datetime.now()?

Comment: e.g. `datetime.strftime(datetime.utcnow(), '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')` - just modify the format string as you like, see e.g. [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime) (scroll down to "Format Code List"). Btw, I'd use UTC to make this a bit more universal. Or add the timezone, but I guess this would make things overly complicated for this purpose.

Comment: hi , i tried and having issues still , could you more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
with open("sensor reading {}.txt".format(datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M')), "ab") as ff:
    np.savetxt(ff, np.expand_dims(timestamped_camera_readings, axis=0),fmt='%f')
```

Comment: @furas sorry, yes you are right, but i think it should come right after "ctime()" as "ab" is a paremeter to "open" suggesting the file to be opened in "append and byte" mode.

Comment: hei , now im having one file for active second. 
how to end up with only one file.

Comment: instead of "ctime()" you can use `datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')` this will generate a filename which will remain unique for a day. and this `datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M')` will give you a unique file for a minute.

Comment: any ways to name it as a single file and file name as the current time ???

Comment: just make the file name outside the loop and as long as the name remains unique, the same will open again and again. right now, this line is probably being executed inside some loop which creates a new name every minute.